# WCF service Endpoint X509 certificate Identity

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, wcf-security

I have service on one machine which I would like to access from another machine.
So I need a help with setting the identity of the endpoints because i am getting

```
The identity check failed for the outgoing message. The expected identity is 'identity(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/right/possessproperty:http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/thumbprint)' (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/thumbprint%29%27) for the 'net.tcp:...' target endpoint.
```

My service is configured to use certificate for transport security and validation mode is set to ChainTrust.

What type of identity should I set on the client of this service since I am accessing the service using the ip address of the machine hosting it and not the dns name?
More precisely what EndpointIdentity setting should I set to the EndpointAddress when I am setting the service host and what should I use on the client when I am setting the EndpointAddress?

On both client and the service machine the issuer of the certificates used to secure the transport is in the trusted authorities.